# Prove there exists a diffeomorphism map $f:M\rightarrow M$ such that $f(x)=y$

Tags: manifolds, differential

Let M be a connected smooth manifold, $x,y\in M$,then there exists a diffeomorphism map $f:M\rightarrow M$ such that $f(x)=y$.

Comment: In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, 
and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them 
give their answers at the right level. As it is, your question is phrased as an isolated problem and it does not match many [users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may 
attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, [edit] the question to add more content.

Comment: My belief is that to appreciate the fairly advanced reasoning entailed by an Answer to this, one almost necessarily should be able to Readers more than a terse recitation of an assigned exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x$ be an element of $M$, we may find a chart $x\in U$. Let $f:U\rightarrow f(U)\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be diffeomorphism. There exists $r>0$, such that $B(f(x),r)\subset f(U)$. For every $u\in\mathbb{R}^n$ with $\|u\|<r/2$, consider the vector field $X$ defined on $f(U)$ such that the restriction of $X$ to $B(f(x),r/2)$ is $u$ and the restriction of $X$ to $f(U)-B(f(x),r)$ is zero. This can be done with bump functions. We can pullback $X$ on $U$ with $f$ and it defines a vector fields $Y'$ on $U$ such that the restriction of $Y'$ on $U-f^{-1}(B(f(x),r))$ is zero. $Y'$ can be extended to $M$ by zero in $M-f^{-1}(B(f(x),r))$. Let $Y$ be that extension. The support of $Y$ is compact, so we can define the flow $\phi_t^u$ of $Y$ remark that the family of flow $\phi_t^u$ act transitively in a neighborhood of $x$. Since $M$ is connected, we deduce that $Diff(M)$ acts transitively on $M$.